# Nodes not properly adding to LinkedList

Tags: java

I know I shouldn't be trying to reinvent the wheel, however I'm required to for this assignment. I'm struggling to get any output at all from my LinkedList, I believe my addFirst() method is not properly adding the node or my toString() method is not properly displaying the LinkedList. Any idea why? I've been stumped on this for a bit and not sure where else to look for help.

I'm not getting any errors, just zero output.

Main:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    LinkList theList = new LinkList();

    theList.addFirst("One");
    theList.getFirst();
    theList.size();

    theList.toString();

}   // end main()
```

LinkList.java:

```
public class LinkList {

private Node first;
private Node current;

public LinkList() {
    first = null;
    current = first;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (first == null);
}

public void removeFirst() {
    try {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            Node temp = first;
            first = first.getNext();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
}

public int size() {
    int count = 0;

    if (isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    while (current != null) {
        current = current.getNext();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String str;
    int size = size();
    str = "Size: " + size;
    str += "\nElements:";
    while (current != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            str += "\nNode: " + current.getNext();
        }
    }
    return str;
}

public String getFirst() {
    if (first == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return first.getData();
}

public void addFirst(String data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode.getNext();
    first = newNode;
}

public boolean contains(String target) {
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getData().equals(target)) {
            return true;
        }
        current.getNext();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Node.java

```
public class Node {

private String data;
private Node next;

public Node(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Node: " + getData();
}

}
```

Comment: You're not actually printing anything anywhere.  Voting to close as off-topic as your issue is down to a typo and unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should surround calls you want to see output of in the console with `System.out.println();`,  e.g.:

```
System.out.println(theList.size());
System.out.println(theList.toString());
```

Note that you don't need to call `toString()` method explicitly in the second line, `System.out.println(theList);` calls `theList`'s `toString()` method automatically and it's equivalent to `System.out.println(theList.toString());`.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked S.O.P, thanks! Any idea why Size returns 0?

Comment: Because the "current" object field is not set and all methods only look to that value.

Comment: You should initialize `current` with `first` before each iteration. It would also be better to have `current` as a method-local variable instead of an instance variable.

Comment: As an addition to other helpful comments - if you look into `size()` implementation, you'll notice that the only possibility to return 0 from this method (as you're sure that you added objects to `theList`) is not entering while loop in this method (so it seems that `current` is equal to `null`).

Answer (score 1):

In your `addFirst()` method, you should:

- Create the new node
- Set the current `first` node as the next node of the new node
- Set the new node as `first`

You're missing one of the above steps.

Additionally, all of the methods that include iterating the list (`toString()`, `size()` etc.) would need to initialize with `current = first;` before the iteration starts. Otherwise `current` can be `null` and the iteration won't start.